# how to set permission when create temporary files on laravel centos?

Tags: laravel, apache, permissions, centos, php-ziparchive

I want to make a zip file and force to download it when user click button download.
Actually it work on windows with xampp

but on centos apache, all files size become 0 kb

```html
 $zip = new \ZipArchive();

 $uploaddir = public_path().'/temp'; 

        $tmp_file = tempnam($uploaddir,'');
        $zip->open($tmp_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE);
             
         // Loop through each file
                foreach($files as $file){
                     $url2 = $url.$file->upload;
                     $url2 = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url2);

                        if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
                            die('CURL is not installed!');
                        }

                     $ch = curl_init();
                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
                     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                     $output = curl_exec($ch);
                     curl_close($ch);
                     $download_file = $output;

                     $type = substr($url2, -5, 5); 
                     #add it to the zip
                     $zip->addFromString(basename($url.$file->upload.'.'.$type),$download_file);
                }
                // close zip
                $zip->close();
            

        
                // Set Time Download
                date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
                $time_name = date('Ymd');
                $time_download = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $log_download = new Log_download;
                
                $user = Auth::user();
                $id_user =  $user->id;
                $log_download->id_praapplication   =  $id_pra;
                $log_download->id_user   =  $id_user;
                $log_download->Activity   =  'Download ZIP File';
                $log_download->type   =  'Zip Archive';
                $log_download->downloaded_at   =  $time_download;
                $log_download->save();
                
                # send the file to the browser as a download
               ob_start();
               $strFile = file_get_contents($tmp_file);         

                header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=DOC-'.$id_pra.'-'.'.zip');
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                  echo $tmp_file;
                  while (ob_get_level()) {
                    ob_end_clean();
                  }
                  readfile($tmp_file);  

                //$filetopath=$public_dir.'/'.$zipFileName;
               //$filetopath = public_path().'/storage/uploads/file/'. $id_pra.'/'.$zipFileName;
                    // Create Download Response
                   // if(file_exists($filetopath)){
                       // return response()->download($filetopath,$zipFileName,$headers);
                    //} 
                exit;
```

here is my code. so every click will create TEMPORARY FILES.
why i dont save zip file to folder? because i have multi step, and every step customer will upload files, and admin can download the file with zip button function.

the problem in centos is, the temporary files permission always become 0666 instead 0755

how to make default 0755 when create the temporary file?

Comment: Rather than dealing with permissions (chmod), I suggest you set the correct ownership (chown). Try setting the ownership of your application folder to the user your Apache is running (probably `apache` or `www-data`).

Comment: hi i already make this
chown -R apache.apache /var/www/xxx
chmod -R 755 /var/www/xxx
chmod -R 755 /var/www/xxx/storage

but everytime temporary files created the permission will be 0666

Comment: I believe that's the default permission for files. Once you've set the proper ownership, there shouldn't be much issues with web server reading/writing inside your application directory. Do you get any errors? Also make sure the directories such as `/temp` and `/storage/uploads/file/../` exists.

Comment: yes, the folder is exist, but everty temp file created inside /public/temp/
files.tmp permission will be 0666 instead 0755

on cpanel and windows its work, permission set to 0755 but on centos problem

Comment: I don't see how what's wrong with 0666. Please share any errors. Also do some debug throughout your code to narrow down where it's happening. It's bad practice to have files with 0755 security wise anyway.

Comment: all files on the zip folder become 0 KB, cannot open, sorry the permission is 0600, NOT 0666

Comment: hi add i this   chmod($tmp_file, 0755);  before readfile($tmp_file);  
the permission correct but all files stillr return size 0 Kb, why its happened only on centos ya? on cpanel all work